# Xpath to get information in next sibling tag using Scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to get my hands on Scrapy and right now I try to extract information from an etymology website: http://www.etymonline.com
Right now, I just want to get the words and their raw description. This is how a usual HTML code chunk is presented in etymonline:

```html
<dt>
  <a href="/index.php?term=address&allowed_in_frame=0">address (n.)</a>
  <a href="http://dictionary.reference.com/search?q=address" class="dictionary" title="Look up address at Dictionary.com">
    <img src="graphics/dictionary.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Look up address at Dictionary.com" title="Look up address at Dictionary.com"/>
  </a>
</dt>
<dd>
  1530s, "dutiful or courteous approach," from <a href="/index.php?term=address&allowed_in_frame=0" class="crossreference">address</a> (v.) and from French <span class="foreign">adresse</span>. Sense of "formal speech" is from 1751. Sense of "superscription of a letter" is from 1712 and led to the meaning "place of residence" (1888).
</dd>
```

The word is contained in the `<dt>`tag and the description in the next sibling, `<dd>` tag.
To get the list of word on a page like http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=a&p=9&allowed_in_frame=0, it's possible to write `word = sel.xpath('//dl/dt/a/text()').extract()`.

Then I tried to loop over this list of words and extract the relevant information using this line of code `info = selInfo.xpath("//dl/dt[a='"+word[i]+"']/following-sibling::dd")`. But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have the _full_ content of the `<a>` element in `word[i]` (so, for instance: "address (n.)", not "address"? Otherwise, you might want to use `starts-with`.

Answer (score 5):

To get to the `<dd>` after a `<dt>`, you can use the `following-sibling` axis, you're correct.

`following-sibling::dd` with select all `dd` elements after the context node. Therefore you need to restrict the XPath to only the first one, using a position predicate `[1]`.

For each `dt` element you get out of `//dl/dt`, you select `following-sibling::dd[1]`.

Here's a sample session using `scrapy shell` for the term "address":

```
$ scrapy shell "http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=address&searchmode=none"
...
2014-11-26 10:34:53+0100 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=address&searchmode=none> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7f1396cc6950>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=address&searchmode=none>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=address&searchmode=none>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7f1397399bd0>
[s]   spider     <Spider 'default' at 0x7f13966c05d0>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser

In [1]: for dt in response.xpath('//dl/dt'):
    print "Word:", dt.xpath('string(a)').extract()
    print "Definition:", dt.xpath('string(following-sibling::dd[1])').extract()
    print
   ...:     
Word: [u'address (n.)']
Definition: [u'1530s, "dutiful or courteous approach," from address (v.) and from French adresse. Sense of "formal speech" is from 1751. Sense of "superscription of a letter" is from 1712 and led to the meaning "place of residence" (1888).']

Word: [u'addressee (n.)']
Definition: [u'1810; see address (v.) + -ee.']

Word: [u'address (v.)']
Definition: [u'early 14c., "to guide or direct," from Old French adrecier "go straight toward; straighten, set right; point, direct" (13c.), from Vulgar Latin *addirectiare "make straight," from Latin ad "to" (see ad-) + *directiare, from Latin directus "straight, direct" (see direct (v.)). Late 14c. as "to set in order, repair, correct." Meaning "to write as a destination on a written message" is from mid-15c. Meaning "to direct spoken words (to someone)" is from late 15c. Related: Addressed; addressing.']

Word: [u'salutatorian (n.)']
Definition: [u'1841, American English, from salutatory "of the nature of a salutation," here in the specific sense "designating the welcoming address given at a college commencement" (1702) + -ian. The address was originally usually in Latin and given by the second-ranking graduating student.']

...

Word: [u'reverend (adj.)']
Definition: [u'early 15c., "worthy of respect," from Middle French reverend, from Latin reverendus "(he who is) to be respected," gerundive of revereri (see reverence). As a form of address for clergymen, it is attested from late 15c.; earlier reverent (late 14c. in this sense). Abbreviation Rev. is attested from 1721, earlier Revd. (1690s). Very Reverend is used of deans, Right Reverend of bishops, Most Reverend of archbishops.']

Word: [u'nun (n.)']
Definition: [u'Old English nunne "nun, vestal, pagan priestess, woman devoted to religious life under vows," from Late Latin nonna "nun, tutor," originally (along with masc. nonnus) a term of address to elderly persons, perhaps from children\'s speech, reminiscent of nana (compare Sanskrit nona, Persian nana "mother," Greek nanna "aunt," Serbo-Croatian nena "mother," Italian nonna, Welsh nain "grandmother;" see nanny).']


In [2]:
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea for your **xpath** to work is not to `loop` the extracted list, but within a parent node in **xpath**.

I don't have **scrapy** on my mac at the moment, but the technique here should similarly apply, like this:

```
# I use lxml for loose html string parsing
from lxml import html

s = '''<dt><a href="/index.php?term=address&allowed_in_frame=0">address (n.)</a> <a href="http://dictionary.reference.com/search?q=address" class="dictionary" title="Look up address at Dictionary.com"><img src="graphics/dictionary.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Look up address at Dictionary.com" title="Look up address at Dictionary.com" /></a></dt>
<dd>1530s, "dutiful or courteous approach," from <a href="/index.php?term=address&allowed_in_frame=0" class="crossreference">address</a> (v.) and from French <span class="foreign">adresse</span>. Sense of "formal speech" is from 1751. Sense of "superscription of a letter" is from 1712 and led to the meaning "place of residence" (1888).</dd>'''

sel = html.fromstring(s)

# rather than extracting the words straight away, you loop from the parent xpath
for nodes in sel.xpath('//dt'):
    # then access a node to get the text
    print nodes.xpath('a/text()')
    # and go back to parent and search the dd node
    print nodes.xpath('../dd/text()')

# sample results
['address (n.)']
['1530s, "dutiful or courteous approach," from ', ' (v.) and from French ', '. Sense of "formal speech" is from 1751. Sense of "superscription of a letter" is from 1712 and led to the meaning "place of residence" (1888).']
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using following-sibling.

```
class SingleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "etym"
    allowed_domains = ["etymonline.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=d&allowed_in_frame=0"]

    def parse(self, response):


        for nodes in response.xpath('//dl'):
            for i in nodes.xpath('dt'):
                print i.xpath('a/text()').extract()   
                print i.xpath('following-sibling::dd[1]/text()').extract()
```

Basically:

- you get Dt element one by one
- print the text contained in the link
- move to the next sibling and print the text contained
- List item

Here it is an extract of the output:

> [u'daiquiri (n.)'] [u'type of alcoholic drink, 1920 (first recorded in
>   F. Scott Fitzgerald), from ', u', name of a district or village in
>   eastern Cuba.']
>
> [u'dairy (n.)'] [u'late 13c., "building for making butter and cheese;
>   dairy farm," formed with Anglo-French ', u' affixed to Middle English
>   ', u' (in ', u' "dairymaid"), from Old English ', u' "kneader of
>   bread, housekeeper, female servant" (see ', u' (n.1)). The purely
>   native word was ', u'.']
>
> [u'dais (n.)'] [u'mid-13c., from Anglo-French ', u', Old French ', u'
>   "table, platform," from Latin ', u' "disk-shaped object," also, by
>   medieval times, "table," from Greek ', u' "quoit, disk, dish" (see ',
>   u' (n.)). Died out in English c.1600, preserved in Scotland, revived
>   19c. by antiquarians.']